# Google+ signin not granting circles

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am developing a web application where I want to allow google+ login. I am asking for the plus.login permission which should (among other things) grant me access to the user's circled people list.

The problem is that when I request for the circled list people.list with visible collection, I get an empty response.

After some time researching, I found out that if I go to the list of user application configuration page in Google+ and I add all circles explicitly there (the option is called "Advanced connection settings"). Then it works.
Another way it works is if the user edits the list of circles on the authorization popup (where ironically all of them are selected by default, so I would assume that in that case I should get access to them even if I didn't click on edit).

I guess I am doing something wrong, because I cannot understand why Google+ would force the user to authorize you in such a subtile way.
Here is the code I use for requesting the permissions:

```
gapi.signin.render(name, {
    'callback': googlePlusSignUp,
    'clientid': '<KEY>',
     'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
     'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
     'accesstype': 'offline'
});
```

Has somebody an idea about what I might be doing wrong? Are there a way of explicitly asking for all the circles? Maybe it's some setting from the user?

Thanks!